# Weird behavior of trampolining

Tags: javascript, thunk, trampolines

Recently I've been doing some JS tasks on codewars and encountered this task [Tail recursion with trampoline](https://www.codewars.com/kata/53d045892578b1be8b0001c4).
Here we need to create thunk function and trampoline function in order to get rid of annoying 
*RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded*.
So i tried this code:

```js
function thunk(fn) { 
  let args = [...arguments].slice(1, arguments.length);
  return function () { 
    return fn.apply(null, args);
  };
};

function trampoline(thunk) {
  while (typeof thunk === 'function') {
    thunk = thunk();
  }
  return thunk; 
}

function isEven(n) {
  let arg = n;

  function _isEven() {
    return (arg === 0 ? true : isOdd(arg - 1));
  };

  return trampoline(thunk(_isEven, n));
}

function isOdd(n) {
  let arg = n;

  function _isOdd() {
    return (arg === 0 ? false : isEven(arg - 1));
  };

  return trampoline(thunk(_isOdd, n));
}
```

And this didn't work, there still was RangeError.
But after i added console.log() to _isOdd or _isEven it doesn't throw error and passes all the tests. Like this:

```js
function thunk(fn) { 
  let args = [...arguments].slice(1, arguments.length);
  return function () { 
    return fn.apply(null, args);
  };
};

function trampoline(thunk) {
  while (typeof thunk === 'function') {
    thunk = thunk();
  }
  return thunk; 
}

function isEven(n) {
  let arg = n;

  function _isEven() {
    console.log();
    return (arg === 0 ? true : isOdd(arg - 1));
  };

  return trampoline(thunk(_isEven, n));
}

function isOdd(n) {
  let arg = n;

  function _isOdd() {
    return (arg === 0 ? false : isEven(arg - 1));
  };

  return trampoline(thunk(_isOdd, n));
}
```

I understood mistake and rewrote the code, but haven't understood why does it work when I add console.log().

Comment: I don't know exactly how, but it seams this is due to tail call optimization introduce in EcmaScript 6. There are rules how the compiler detects if a function is in a tail position. And probably the nested function with only a return confuses the optimizer, if the function is declared above the return of the outer function. Perhaps you could try out to move the inner function below the outer return, to test that. Here is a link to the rules the optimizer works with: https://2ality.com/2015/06/tail-call-optimization.html.

Comment: I'm interested in this too but I'm actually busy. So I'll try it later on and report if I find something. If you find out something before me, please add an answer yourself and mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

The right solution for this task is as follows:

```js
function thunk(fn /*, args */) {
  return fn.bind.apply(fn, arguments);
}


function trampoline(thunk) {
  while(typeof (thunk=thunk()) == "function");
  return thunk;
}

function _isOdd(n) {
  return (n === 0 ? false : thunk(_isEven, n - 1));
}
function _isEven(n) {
  return (n === 0 ? true : thunk(_isOdd, n - 1));
}
function isEven(n) {
  return trampoline(thunk(_isEven, n));
}

function isOdd(n) {
  return trampoline(thunk(_isOdd, n));
}
```